# Why does my XAML app not show

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently trying to make an wpf application.
The problem is when I run the app I only get a white rectangle.
I've searched a lot, but I simply cannot see an error.

I'm a wpf beginner, so If there is also some other error, or something which can be done better please tell me. THANKZ!

Here's the xaml code. (I hav nothing coded at the moment, only xaml...)

```
    <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Visu"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Test.Visu.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
        Left="0" Top="0">
   <Window.Resources>
      <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="date" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}"/>
   </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="250"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!-- TOP Panel-->
        <Grid x:Name="TopPanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            Height="{Binding RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight, ElementName=MainGrid}"
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkColorKey}}"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight, ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="269"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight, ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="PageNumberButton" Content="100" Grid.Column="0"
                Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=TopPanel}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=TopPanel}"
                Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}" Click="PageNumberButton_Click"/>
            <Label x:Name="PageTitleLabel" Content="PageTitle" Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="16" 
                Width="319"
                Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=TopPanel}" 
                BorderBrush ="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <!--<local:TopMenu Grid.Column="2"/>-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="BtnProcess" Content="Process" Margin="1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}"
                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnMenu" Content="Menu" Margin="1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}"
                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Content="Login" Margin="1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}"
                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnExit" Content="Exit" Margin="1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}"
                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopPanel}" Click="BtnExit_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <!-- Date/Time Panel-->
            <Grid x:Name="DateTimePanel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Grid.Column="3"
                Width="125"
                Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=TopPanel}">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/logo.bmp" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Content=" "/>
                <Label x:Name="DateLabel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="11"
                    Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource date}, StringFormat=\{0:MM.dd.yy\}}" />
                <Label x:Name="TimeLabel" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="11"
                    Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource date}, StringFormat=\{0:HH:mm:ss\}}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <DockPanel x:Name="MainPanel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            Height="{Binding RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight, ElementName=MainGrid}"
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
            Background="#FFF9DCB6">
            <Label Content="Main Panel" Height="462" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="32"/>
        </DockPanel>
      <!-- BOTTOM Panel -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="BottomPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
            Height="{Binding RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight, ElementName=MainGrid}"
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"   >
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkColorKey}}"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(in the upper right panel I want to display the date and time. Is this possible to update it automatically this way?)

Here are some screenshots:

Blend shows the window correctly:
[image: blend]
Visual Studio sometimes also only displays a white rectangle:
[image: studio]
The app running is only a white rectangle:
[image: running]

Furthermore I need to get rid of the frame border from Windows, but this is already on my list.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Things like `Height="{Binding RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight, ElementName=MainGrid}"` or `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}"` do not make any sense at all. The parent Grid already resizes its children to the size of their cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all your Xaml width and height binding:

```
Height="{Binding RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight, ElementName=MainGrid}"
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}"
```

This is what causing the mess, set all to "Auto" for example and you will see your screen, then make proper adjustements.

Comment: Do not set them at all. `Auto` is the default value.

Comment: I removed all the width/height bindings and the butons and everything "appeared". Now I had to put back some again to have my design as a need it. THANKS!